# Excel: Countif contains referenced cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have a countifs statement and one of the requirements is a contains. If I type it like this :

```
=(COUNTIFS(Table2[[#All],[Stars]],"3.5",Table2[[#All],[Group]],"* Bob*"))
```

it returns the correct number, but if I type it like this:

```
 =(COUNTIFS(Table2[[#All],[Stars]],"3.5",Table2[[#All],[Group]],"* G3*"))
```

and cell G3 says Bob, it returns 0.

Answer (score 1):

"* G3*" is not a reference to cell G3, it is the exact text "* G3*".

You need to move 'G3' outside of the quotation marks, e.g.:

> =(COUNTIFS(Table2[[#All],[Stars]],"3.5",Table2[[#All],[Group]],"* "&G3&"*"))